# ¿Cómo eliminar columnas en un objeto sf?

Tags: r

Tengo un objeto `sf` con 7.000 observaciones y 17 variables. Para agilizar los procesos de análisis geoespacial, quiero deshacerme de las variables que no me son de utilidad. 
He intentado emplear el comando `select`, pero parece ser que no funciona con objetos `sf`. ¿Cómo se puede hacer esa operación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un objeto `sf` extiende la funcionalidad de un `data.frame` normal, por lo que puedes eliminar una variable, como lo harías con un `dataframe`, o al menos con una de las formas en que se puede hacer,  es decir `objeto$nombre_variable <- NULL`:

```
library("sf")

# Creamos un sf con dos variables
g = st_sf(a=3:4, st_sfc(st_point(1:2), st_point(3:4)))
g$Variable1 <- runif(1)
g$Variable2 <- runif(1)
names(g)

[1] ""          "Variable1" "Variable2"

# Borramos una de las variables
g$Variable1 <- NULL
names(g)

[1] ""          "Variable2"
```

Eventualmente, para eliminar más de una variable:

```
g[c(3,4)] <- NULL
g[c("Variable1","Variable2")] <- NULL
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias. Ya puestos, ¿hay alguna forma de borrar más de una a la vez?

Comment: Hola @JesúsPinilla, te respondo en mi nueva edición de la respuesta. saludos.